# networkx: getting a flow decomposition

Tags: python, networkx, max-flow

I am solving a maximum flow problem for a network, but I'm interested in the paths that are identified by the various algorithms, not just the maximum flow value.

My problem is a multiple-source / multiple-sink type, which I convert to a standard s-t flow by adding a super-source and a super-sink. I can use [nx algorithms](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/flow.html) to compute the max flow.

However, I could not find any  way to get the list of paths. Some algorithms, like [Dinitz](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.flow.dinitz.html) return a residual network, which is again based on arc flow and capacity.

Please let me know if there is any option that I am missing here.

Comment: ```maximum_flow()``` returns a ```flow_dict``` that contains the value of the flow that went through each edge, does it works for you?
https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.flow.maximum_flow.html#networkx.algorithms.flow.maximum_flow

Comment: I looked at that - it wont work as I need the list of paths and the corresponding flow_value. flow_dict provides the value of the total flow for each edge, i.e. aggregated across all the paths using that edge.